# Two firebase get() inside each other makes the global variable becomes null and can only handle the first document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase database that looks like this:
[image: Inside 'canvas' collection, there are many data as well.]

Now, what I need is to retrieve every document inside 'canvas', including their name field. So, what I did is retrieving the document's name, and from that, I retrieve canvas documents of every single documents.

```
function getDatabase() {
    let rowId = 0;
    dbRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

            // HTML for each row
            let $idEmo = $("<th>", { "scope": "row" });
            let $canvasEmo = $("<th>");
            let $nameEmo = $("<th>");
            let $dateEmo = $("<th>");
            let $canvasEmoContent = $("<canvas>")
            $canvasEmoContent.attr({
                width: "100",
                height: "100",
                id: "db-canvas-" + rowId
            });

            // Prepend data into one row
            $idEmo.prepend(rowId);
            $canvasEmo.prepend($canvasEmoContent);
            $nameEmo.prepend(doc.data().name);
            $dateEmo.prepend(doc.data().date);

            let $tableRow = $("<tr>");
            $tableRow.addClass("t-row");
            $tableRow.prepend($idEmo, $canvasEmo, $nameEmo, $dateEmo);
            $("#emoji-table-body").append($tableRow);

            // Get the circles from the database in each row
            let dbCircle = R.clone(circleTemplate);
            dbRef.doc(doc.data().name).collection("canvas").get()
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach((bit) => {
                        let i = 8 * bit.data().posY + bit.data().posX;
                        dbCircle[i].posX = bit.data().posX;
                        dbCircle[i].posY = bit.data().posY;
                        dbCircle[i].isOn = bit.data().isOn;
                        dbCircle[i].color = bit.data().color;
                    });
                })
                .then(() => {
                    
                    makeDatabaseCanvas("db-canvas-" + rowId, dbCircle)
                    console.log(dbCircle)
                    console.log(dbCircle[3].isOn)
                    console.log(rowId)
                    rowId++;
                })
            
        });
    });
}
```

Other functions:

```
    function makeDatabaseCanvas(id, dCircle) {
    renderBoard(id, 100);
    for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        renderCircle(id, dCircle[i].posX, dCircle[i].posY, dCircle[i].isOn, dCircle[i].color, 4);
    }
}

    function renderBoard(id, size) {
    let context = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
}

// Circle rendering
function renderCircle(id, row, column, isOn, color, scale) {
    let context = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
    let centerX = (row * 50 + 25) / scale;
    let centerY = (column * 50 + 25) / scale;
    let radius = 20 / scale;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fillStyle = ((isOn) ? color : '#FFFFFF');
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}
```

The problem with this is: for the second Foreach and onward, the variable **rowId** just... disappears. Everything is fine for the first **Foreach** (the **makeDatabaseCanvas** method works perfectly), but for the 2nd one, and onward, the console return the **rowId** is null. Here is the error returned.

[image: The first foreach is fine, but the 2nd one has problems. The 'getContext' should receive the rowId]

At this point, I have tried many solutions. I tried **async/await** but **Foreach** expects a synchronous function. I tried replacing it with **For loop** and... it returned nothing. I tried to put the name of the document inside an array and use **async/await** on it, but it also failed.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: The error comes from the code to get the canvas id from the **rowId** (because I link them together for easier coding). Since it cannot access **rowId**, it cannot access the canvas id as well. I have editted the codes a bit to make them easier to be shown on Stackoverflow. So the whole codes are like that.

[image: The codes outside of the scope still works. They are used to create a row with canvas tag. The problem codes are used to draw on the canvas]

And as you can see in the picture, the first one is drawn perfectly. However, the second one cannot be drawn. The id does not increase, and the id of the 2nd canvas is '**db-canvas-0**' where it should be 1.

Comment: I don't see anything here that suggests rowId is ever null.  The error message is saying that something related to getContext was null.

Comment: My bad. The code for it is "let context = document.getElementById("canvas-" + rowId).getContext('2d')". I assign the id of canvas with the id of the row. I will update the post.

Comment: Why bother looking up elements by ID when you already have a reference to them in a variable, ie `$canvasEmoContent`?

Comment: There are many other functions use the function **renderBoard()** and **renderCircle()** as well, so I need to search for id to get the context of the canvas. Also, it was my first time learning canvas so I separated everything about it in another function for better debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line of code:

```
dbRef.doc(doc.data().name).collection("canvas").get()
```

to

```
dbRef.doc(doc.id).collection("canvas").get()
```

You should reference the document itself rather than referencing on the document's data object.

You could also check the code that I wrote which also gets data from the collection, documents and its subcollection.

```
dbRef = db.collection("collection");

let  rowId = 0;

    dbRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
        document.ref.collection("sub_collection").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            //Prepend Row HTML Data.
            console.log({main_collection_data:{rowId:rowId, data:document.data()}});
            rowId++;
            querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
                // Get the circles from the database in each row
                console.log({sub_collection_data:{data:document.data()}});
            });
        })
      })
    });
```

---

Appending HTML in the 1st `foreach` results to:

```
{
  main_collection_data: {
    rowId: 0,
    data: { date: '17-1-2022', name: 'Window' }
  }
}
{ main_collection_data: { rowId: 0, data: { test: 'test' } } }
{ main_collection_data: { rowId: 0, data: { test: 'test' } } }
{ sub_collection_data: { data: { test: 'test', test2: 'test' } } }
{ sub_collection_data: { data: { test: 'test', test2: 'test' } } }
{ sub_collection_data: { data: { test: 'test', test2: 'test' } } }
```

It gets the all data from the main collection before getting the data from the sub-collection which blocks you from rendering the canvas coming from the sub-collection which as you can see is not what you want. It should be as procedural as possible.

```
Row Data
 - Main Collection
    - Sub-Collection
```

By appending the HTML into the `get()` of the sub-collection, results to:

```
{
  main_collection_data: {
    rowId: 0,
    data: { date: '17-1-2022', name: 'Window' }
  }
}
{ sub_collection_data: { data: { test: 'test', test2: 'test' } } }
{ main_collection_data: { rowId: 1, data: { test: 'test' } } }
{ sub_collection_data: { data: { test: 'test', test2: 'test' } } }
{ main_collection_data: { rowId: 2, data: { test: 'test' } } }
{ sub_collection_data: { data: { test: 'test', test2: 'test' } } }
```

It procedurally gets the data starting from its main collection to main collection's object then to the sub-collection to its sub-collection's data which is your use-case scenario.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Instead of putting rowId++ into the end, and the HTML prepend after first **forEach**, I put them right after the 2nd querysnapshot just like your solution.  Also, you help me a lot with the document reference; I had some trouble referencing it before. May I ask why putting the **HTML appends** into the scope of **get()**  makes it works while putting them in the 1st **forEach** makes it stop working?

Comment: Hi @WinstonLycan, I've updated my answer with explanation.